# Clear cells that contain #NUM! in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code that clears cells that contain #NUM!

```
Dim CLR As Range
 For Each CLR In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
       If CLR.Text = "#NUM!" Then
CLR.ClearContents
       End If
 Next
```

The problem is that these few lines of code slow down my program. A lot. I was wondering if there's another way to do it, since I need to delete these values in order to execute another macros.

I have already tried to shorten this to a smaller range instead of searching for the last cell used. However, it took the same amount of time or I didn't notice the difference.

```
Dim CLR As Range
     For Each CLR In ActiveSheet.Range("Q3:BA2500")
           If CLR.Text = "#NUM!" Then
    CLR.ClearContents
           End If
     Next
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you running the code?  you did not include the beginning and the end of your sub   ....note: `CLR.ClearContents` should be indented another two levels

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reasonable number of cells containing errors, the following code will clear all error values (not just #NUM!):

```
ActiveSheet.Range("Q3:BA2500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents
```

Note that this will error out if there are more than 8'192 distinct areas containing errors. It will also error out if there are no error cells found. I'll let you tackle the error handling.

Comment: To avoid 2nd issue you can wrap code in `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`

Comment: And to avoid the 1st issue you can scan the range column by column.